Question about the proof of argument principle
I am reading the proof of the argument principle in Stein's book. The theorem is a natural corollary of the residue theorem. However, one thing is confusing to me. Do we need to state that $f'/f$ has only finite singularities? Or can we say $f$ has only finite poles and zeros?
Theorem 4.1 (Argument principle) Suppose $f$ is meromorphic in an open set containing a circle $C$ and its interior. If $f$ has no poles and never vanishes on $C$, then
$$
\begin{array}{r}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{f^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)} d z=(\text { number of zeros of } f \text { inside } C \text { ) minus } \\
\text { (number of poles of } f \text { inside } C \text { ), }
\end{array}
$$
where the zeros and poles are counted with their multiplicities.
More generally, it also holds for toy contours.
